# Подсоединить к button ссылку на файл Contact.php

Tags: php, html5

```
<h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title"> 600 рублей  <small class="text-muted">/ День</small></h1>
<ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
    <li>На разовое занятие</li>
    <li>В любой день</li>
    <li>Групповое</li>
    <li>Стоимость одного занятия 600 рублей.</li>
</ul>
```

Оставить заявку

Comment: `<a href="">` уже не модно?

Comment: <a href="#"><button type="button"  class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary"  >Оставить заявку</button></a> вот так ты имеешь ввиду ?

Comment: я сделал , как я сейчас написал и не срабатывало

Comment: ну так вы ссылку делайте на нужный вам файл, а не на хэш

Comment: а других вариантов нет?

Comment: А зачем вам другие варианты, если этот рабочий?

Comment: @user389831
Если так хочется других вариантов, то мы найдём, но зачем?

<button onclick="location.href='ССЫЛКА_НА_ФАЙЛ'">Кнопка</button>